# What is the smallest superdeficient number of the form n = p^2*q where p & q are different primes?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving

superdeficient means the sum of n's proper factors that are less than n, when multiplied by 2 are less than n. 
E.g 35 is superdeficient since 1+5+7=13*2=26<35?

Comment: Do you mean $p^{2q}$ or $(p^2)q$?

Comment: The latter option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sufficient and necessary condition is 
$$(1+\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p^2})(1+\frac{1}{q})<\frac{3}{2},$$
so the minimal such number is $5^2*7$.

Comment: wow thanks, but can you elaborate

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion and why 3/2?

Comment: Your condition is $2(\sigma(n)-n)<n$ what is equivalent to $\sigma(n)/n<3/2$.

Comment: Yes but why is it less than 3/2?

Comment: And where did the number 3/2 come from?

Comment: How did you find the minimal number?

Comment: Here $p,q>2$, cases with one of primes is equal to $3$ you can check by brute force

Comment: so how did the inequality aid you in finding 5^2*7?

Comment: Please read my peviois comments, it is elementary calculations